# Laravel - Filter using Between Dates and a Dropdown

Tags: excel, laravel

I am combining two tables to generate a report that will be exported to excel. It should be filtered using between dates and parameter in dropdownlist

I have created the model, query in the controller and also the view. I can export the report to excel, but don't know how to filter it in the controller and view. The two tables are:

1. users (User: id,name,username)
2. played_game (PlayedGame: id, user_id, game, created_at)

Controller

```
public function playersPerGame()//public function playersPerGame(Request $request)
    {
        $games = DB::table('played_game')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as no_of_players, game'))
                     ->groupBy('game')
                     ->get();   
         return view('report.playersPerGame', compact('games'));
    } 
     public function playersExport() {

     $players = PlayedGame::select( 
               "game",
               \DB::raw("SUM(count(*)) as `no_of_players`"))
               //->groupBy("game")        
               ->get();               
     // Initialize the array which will be passed into the Excel
     // generator.
     $playersArray = []; 

     // Define the Excel spreadsheet headers
     $playersArray[] = ['Games', 'No. of Players'];

     // Convert each member of the returned collection into an array,
     // and append it to the payments array.
     foreach ($players as $player) {
          $playersArray[] = $player->toArray();
     }
```

route

```
    Route::get('/report/players-per-game', ['as' => 'playersPerGame', 'uses' => 'ReportController@playersPerGame']);
    Route::get('/report/players-export', 'ReportController@playersExport')->name('players-export');
```

view

```
    <div class="col-xs-4 left-padding">

        <a href="{{ route('games-export') }}" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
</div>

          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">

 <!--
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <div class="box box-info">
                    -->
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed" id="commenter_info_table">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Player</td>
            <td>No. of Games</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($players as $key => $player)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $player->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $player->no_game }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I get to the view page:

1. I want to filter using between dates (played_game.created_at), dropdownlists (users.name and played_game.game) before exporting to excel

Comment: This kind of filtering should be done with a GET request and the filters should be passed in the query string. The implementation can be done in many ways. You will need a html form, and you can use an AJAX request (requires some js) or a regular request.

Comment: How do I achieve that?

Comment: In laravel, you can get the query parameters with `$request->all()` and use them to make a appropriate SQL query. As for the front end part, you can make a form with method "get" or "post" and action should be the route that is resolved with your controller's method. If you are struggling with this I would recommend taking some time to learn how http requests work.